# Airflow Exception - Task received SIGTERM signal

Tags: airflow

I am running airflow tasks using SSH operator. I am pretty sure that the python program has no error and runs successfully when i run it. But when run from airflow towards the end of program execution I end up with SIGTERM error.

I tried to figure out by looking into various solutions but nothing worked. I tried increasing
**killed_task_cleanup_time = 1200** from 60 in airflow.cfg file. Also tried changing **hostname_callable to socket:gethostname** in airflow.cfg as I received the following warning before this error

`Warning: The recorded hostname xxx does not match this instance's hostname`

```
Error:

[2020-10-15 10:45:34,937] {taskinstance.py:954} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2020-10-15 10:45:34,959] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - SSH operator error: Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 137, in execute
    readq, _, _ = select([channel], [], [], self.timeout)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 956, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
```

Any ideas and suggestions are teally helpful. Stuck with this for a day now

Comment: Please show your code and the entirety of the execution logs.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is triggered by the fact that the RECORDED hostname XXX maps an IP address that is different from the IP address mapped by instance's hostname, throwing a SIGTERM error. So you need to specify the IP mapping for the recorded Hostname XXX

Comment: And how can you specify the IP mapping for the recorded hostname? Please write solutiuons in answers, not with hints!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this thread might help? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-966.

Which version of airflow are you using, and did you check your celery broker settings?
The solution seems to be setting visibility timeout higher than the celery default, which is 1 hour, to prevent celery from re-submitting the job. I believe this only affects tasks created via manual run / CLI (not normally scheduled tasks.)